# combine 2 operations in if confition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have:

```
if @message.save
  @message.deliver_contact
  flash[:success] = t('Your_message_successfully_sent')
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

In this code a message is first saved in the database and afterwards sent out (@message.deliver_contact). But, if the delivering fails, the record was already written away.

I want to reach that:
* I only give the success flash if BOTH operations succeed (saving and sending)
* if ONE operation fails, none of the operations should be executed (or the save should be rolled back).

I'm not experienced, anybody an idea how I should write that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be looking for the and operator `&&`. 'If both the operands are non zero then then condition becomes true.' - [source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm). It allows you to say:

```
if (a == true) && (b == true)
    -# only runs if both a AND b are true
```

To apply this to your example would be:

```
if @message.save && @message.deliver_contact
    flash[:success] = t('Your_message_successfully_sent')
    redirect_to root_url
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

Following up from the comments regarding transactions, you might be wanting something along the lines of:

```
 @message.transaction do
     @message.save
     @message.deliver_contact
     rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
         render :action => 'new'
     end
 end
```

See the "Exception handling and rolling back" section from  [The Rails API - ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). You may need to play around.

Comment: Won't this still create a saved message? I'm thinking a transaction is in order.

Comment: yes, that's what I also ask myself, if @message.deliver_contact fails, the message is already saved?